# Can I split a gziped content-encoding across multiple HTTP chunks?

Tags: gzip, chunked-encoding, content-encoding, http-chunked

Can I split a gziped content-encoding across multiple chunks? Are there any known implementations that fail with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [looks to be the common practice on the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589858/tomcat-gzip-while-chunked-issue#2596295), so I am doubting that there would be a problem.